# Testing if a function derivative is continuous

Tags: calculus, number-theory

How can I methodically test if

$f(x)= \log(x)/x^3$

Has a continuous derivative?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) = \log(x)/x^3$?

Comment: yes. Exactly...

Comment: Just calculate its derivate and prove it is continuos or not.

Comment: I know by visual inspection and calculating the derivative that this function’s derivative is continuous over the interval [n,x] where x takes values of the natural numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notation. I guess you actually meant $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x^{3}}$ which is a product of differentiable functions (although you should also provide the set over which you defined $f$). Morover, $\ln x$ and $\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ are smooth, i.e. they admit derivatives of all orders, so each derivative must be continuous. Notice that again what I just said makes sense only if you provide an appropriate set: on $(0,1]$ what I said is true, but on $[0,1]$ is not.

Comment: That’s very structured yes thanks, the interval is [n,x] where x takes values of positive integers

Comment: we just make use of the theorem which ensures the continuity of a differentiable function.